# I dont have iPhone5, and want test functionality on the same version for my buildup, how can I do that?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making an application, and I have an iPhone 4s and iPad, but don't have an iPhone 5.

Now, the problem is I can test the `UI` without an iPhone5, but how can I check the functionality in iPhone 5 and higher versions of it.

How should I test this?

Comment: use iphone 4-inch/4-inch 64 bit simulator

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your budget... you could use [Xamarin Test Cloud](http://xamarin.com/test-cloud), or [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/) to test on real devices.

Alternatively you could consider asking some real users to beta test it for you.
If you do this, [Test Flight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) or [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) (very simple to use) are good platforms.

Comment: These suggested products are from B2B companies, I used to work for one of them! Licensing costs are for CFO's to review, not developers. Getting yourself on craigslist the iDevices you need to test your app are pennies compared to that!

Answer (score 1):

1) install the stimulator in your mac machine

2) use https://www.testflightapp.com/ and invite some tester to help you do testing in iphone 5 devices.

3) if you are having a html5 based app you can test it here http://iphone5simulator.com/